# Complex bash output

Tags: command-line, bash

I have this:

```
cat ../out/output.out | grep E\(X\) >> res
```

It generate file looks like:

```
E(X)     1.2
E(X)     4.5
...etc...
```

It writes the row with "E(X)" in file res. In fact, it is value of energy wich will be y-data in my future GNU-plot figure. 
I want to write the value of $x in near column, namely smth like this:

```
E(X)     1.2     1
E(X)     4.5     2
...etc...
```

But I don't know how to do what I want.
Please, give me advice

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information. $x = {1.0, 1.1, ... , 5.0}. And I want to get to columns $x and the value of energy. I found the solution: cat ../out/output.out | grep E\(MP2\) | awk '{print $0,"'$x'"}' >> res

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to add the x values:

```
cat ../out/output.out | grep E\(X\) | awk '{print $0"    "NR}' >> res
```

As `awk` can do the job of `cat` and `grep`, too, you can just use

```
awk '/E\(X\)/ {print $0"    "NR}' ../out/output.out >> res
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, but my $x is float and your solution displays this: 1     E(X)     1.5